# Expo start vs. Expo run?

Tags: react-native, expo

While building my react-native app, I encountered a situation that my app is runs safely through "expo run:android", but fails on "expo start" with error codes such as:

```
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

My question is, how come I get error from "expo start" but not in "expo run"? I don't understand why these two methods make different results. Does this mean it is more reliable to use "expo start" for debugging process compared to "expo run"?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between start and run:

```
Start a server for developing your app: npx expo start.

Build and run the native apps locally: npx expo run:ios and npx expo run:android.
```

Possible solutions for your issue:

- Check if Metro is already running: The error message suggests that
  Metro might be running from a different folder. Make sure you don't
  have another Metro instance running for a different project. If so,
  stop the existing Metro process and restart it in the correct project
  directory.
- Clear the Metro cache: Sometimes, the Metro cache can become
  corrupted and cause issues. You can try clearing the cache by running
  the following command in your project directory:

  **expo start --clear**